# Difference between ComputeBuffer and GraphicsBuffer in Unity?

Tags: unity, shaders, compute-shader

At first I thought that `ComputeBuffer`'s could only be used in compute shaders and that `GraphicsBuffer`'s could only be used in materials. But Unity provides overloads for setting `ComputeBuffer` and `GraphicsBuffer` to both compute shaders and materials. So how do they differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that they differ in the type of data that they can hold. A GraphicsBuffer can be used for vertex and index buffers, while a ComputeBuffer can be used for any arbitrary data, which is mostly needed for compute shaders.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as Accepted if it solved your problem.